# Standard way to read barcode after upgrading ZXing.Net from 0.16.5 to 0.16.6

Tags: c#, zxing.net

After upgrading ZXing.Net nuget package from 0.16.5 to 0.16.6 the existing source shows the error:

> Using the generic type 'BarcodeReader' requires 1 type arguments

```
public void ReadBarcode(System.Drawing.Bitmap readerBitmap, BarcodeFormat barcodeFormat)
{
    // here when instantiate the barcode reader object 
    // the error occurs with the new updated nuget package 0.16.6
    var barcodeReader = new ZXing.BarcodeReader();

    barcodeReader.Options.PossibleFormats = new List<BarcodeFormat>();
    barcodeReader.Options.PossibleFormats.Add(barcodeFormat);
    barcodeReader.AutoRotate = true;
    barcodeReader.Options.TryHarder = true;
    barcodeReader.Options.PureBarcode = false;

    ZXing.Result barcodeResult = null;

    try
    {
        barcodeResult = barcodeReader.Decode(readerBitmap);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.LogError($"Exception in barcode lib - {ex.Message}");
    }
```

Should I change from `BarcodeReader` to `BarcodeReaderGeneric` or `IBarcodeReader` or `IBarcodeReaderGeneric` or should I add a parameter `createLuminanceSource`?

I was not able to find existing examples using 0.16.6 and even the documentation still shows the parameterless constructor. [image: BarcodeReader Class ZXing.Net Documentation]

Comment: What environment are you running this in (windows forms?) I've tried your example with 0.16.6 in .net framework 4.7.2 and it compiles and runs fine. If you create a test project with a similar environment does it still happen?

Comment: the message would imply that the `var` is choosing the wrong overload for the class, perhaps due to the way you are referencing it?  do you have duplicate imports in your file?

Comment: WPF with .Net Core 3.1 and using Caliburn.Micro v4.0.x-rc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you get desperate and can't get the `BarcodeReader` which inherits from `BarcodeReader<Bitmap>` to be referenced correctly, you could call the base constructor of `BarcodeReader<Bitmap>` directly which is called when you create a new `BarcodeReader`:

```
var luminanceSource = (Func<Bitmap, LuminanceSource>) (bitmap => new BitmapLuminanceSource(bitmap));
var barcodeReader = new ZXing.BarcodeReader<Bitmap>(null, luminanceSource, null);



//...so on
barcodeReader.Options.PossibleFormats = new List<BarcodeFormat>();
barcodeReader.Options.PossibleFormats.Add(barcodeFormat);
```

Comment: Partly answered my question. I couldn't get BarcodeReader, it always implied if I meant IBarcodeReader. The implementation of BarcoderReader<Bitmap> is now accepted as valid code, but still can't get the BitmapLuminanceSource bit.

Answer (score 4):

If you use ZXing.Net with .Net Core / .Net Standard you have to use one of the different binding packages. They contain specific BarcodeReader implementations for the different image libraries.
https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=zxing.bindings
That's by design because .Net core doesn't include a bitmap implementation in the core package.