# ZXing.NET 0.16.0 HResult=0x80070057

Tags: c#, .net-core, zxing.net

Hi I try to use Barcode Reader by ZXing.

Error:

```
System.ArgumentException


HResult=0x80070057
  Message=Source must be non-null.
  Source=zxing
  StackTrace:
   at ZXing.Binarizer..ctor(LuminanceSource source)
   at ZXing.Common.GlobalHistogramBinarizer..ctor(LuminanceSource source)
   at ZXing.Common.HybridBinarizer..ctor(LuminanceSource source)
   at ZXing.BarcodeReaderGeneric.<>c.<.cctor>b__40_0(LuminanceSource luminanceSource)
   at ZXing.BarcodeReaderGeneric.Decode(LuminanceSource luminanceSource)
   at ZXing.BarcodeReader.Decode(Byte[] barcodeBitmap)
   at FileApi.Controllers.ToolController.BarcodeZXingReader(QrCodeParam inputParam) in C:\Data\GitRepo\FileApi\FileApi\Controllers\ToolController.cs:line 225
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Logged|12_1>d.MoveNext()
```

Code:

```
   Byte[] byteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(inputParam.Input);
    // Create an instance of BarcodeReader class
    var barcodeReader = new BarcodeReader();

    // Set the barcode format you want to read
    barcodeReader.Options.PossibleFormats = new List<BarcodeFormat>
    {
        BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,
        BarcodeFormat.CODE_128,
        BarcodeFormat.EAN_13
    };
    var barcodeResult = barcodeReader.Decode(byteArray);
    if (barcodeResult != null)
        return barcodeResult;
    else return "failed read it";
```

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75238894/10024425

Comment: that is will not working too. Because the error about LuminanceSource  ctor which is null. Maybe this library should give examples on the github code, because newest version is very different with older and harder to understand. Finally I use another library.

Comment: since I using philip's answer, all is well now.  here is it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66250042/standard-way-to-read-barcode-after-upgrading-zxing-net-from-0-16-5-to-0-16-6

Comment: I wrote it here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66311301/1293800
You should use one of the binding packages if you target platform is .Net Core, .Net Standard, .Net 5.0 or above. Only the classic .net framework until 4.x contain a bitmap implementation which is needed for the simple initialization "new BarcodeReader()".

Answer (score 0):

```
public string GetQRImage()
{
    string qrpath = "Your QR image path";
    LuminanceSource barcodeBitmap = new ZXing.Windows.Compatibility.BitmapLuminanceSource(new Bitmap(qrpath));
    // Create a barcode reader instance
    var barcodeReader = new BarcodeReaderGeneric();
    // Decode the barcode
    var result = barcodeReader.Decode(barcodeBitmap);
    if (result == null)
        return "No barcode found.";
    return result.Text;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).